# Storing latitude longitude in cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, cql

How to store latitude and longitude into the Cassandra tables and how to query up the data within 5 kms radius

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very broad and vague, so I will give a very broad answer.

You could store each latitude and longitude as a row in a Cassandra table, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE locations (location text PRIMARY KEY, latitude float, longitude float);
```

Then to find all the locations within a 5 km radius of a specified latitude and longitude (let's call that location X), you'd need to check each row in the table using a client application you would create.

In pure Cassandra, you would SELECT * from the table to get all the rows (using paging if there are a lot of rows), and in your client application, for each row check if the distance between X and the row is less than 5 km, and output rows that match.

Or you could pair Cassandra with Apache spark and do the same calculation in parallel.

But there are a lot of different approaches you could take, so that's just one way.